# How can I copy every 4th file in a Folder into a New Folder?

Tags: windows-explorer, batch-file, file-io

I am exporting an animation as PNG image files.
From the 1199 sequences of frames exported, only every 4th file contains a key frame the rest of the image files are exact duplicates of the previous.

How can I copy only the 4th file into a New Folder?

```
file-20000.png - Copy
file-20001.png - Duplicate of file-20000
file-20002.png - Duplicate of file-20000
file-20003.png - Duplicate of file-20000
file-20004.png - Copy
file-20005.png - Duplicate of file-20004
file-20006.png - Duplicate of file-20004
file-20007.png - Duplicate of file-20004
file-20008.png - Copy
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [FOR /L](https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html) loop and set the **start** to `0`, the **step** to `4` and the **end** to `1200` which is one more than the `1199` number sequences of file name parts which you need only to copy the fourth file.

This will iterate the numbers starting at `0` going from `0, 4, 8, .... 1196`  counting by 4's and you can append the iterated value as a string concatenated within a portion of a file name along with a wildcard mask and use that with [xcopy](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) to copy each **4th** file accordingly.

---

### Batch Script

**Note:** *This logic assumes the file names will always start with **"file-2"** and always end with the sequence numbers just before the dot before the extension `png` (i.e. `<SeqNum>.png`)*.

```
@ECHO ON

SET SrcDir=C:\folder\src
SET DestDir=C:\folder\dest
SET fNamePart=file-2
SET ext=png

FOR /L %%a IN (0, 4, 1200) DO (
    ECHO F | XCOPY /Y /F "%SrcDir%\%fNamePart%*%%a.%ext%" "%DestDir%\"
    )

PAUSE
EXIT
```

---

### Further Resources

- [FOR /L](https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html)

  > ```
  > FOR /L %variable IN (start,step,end) DO command [command-parameters]
  >
  >     The set is a sequence of numbers from start to end, by step amount.
  >     So (1,1,5) would generate the sequence 1 2 3 4 5 and (5,-1,1) would
  >     generate the sequence (5 4 3 2 1)
  > ```
- [XCOPY](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)

Answer (score 0):

If all the files that you want have `Copy` in their names,
and all the files that you don’t want don’t have `Copy` in their names,
then you can use `*Copy*`,
as in

```
copy *Copy* DestinationDirectory
```

or use `*copy*`,
since Windows is case insensitive. 
If all the files that you want have `Copy` *at the end* of their names,
you can use `*Copy` instead (leaving off the `*` at the end). 
You can use filename patterns in Windows Explorer
by typing `file:*copy*` into the search box.